# How can I get VS2019+ to run docker compose?

Tags: .net, docker, visual-studio, docker-compose, azure-functions

I have a solution containing an Azure Function App and my app uses CosmosDb and some other services when debugging/running locally via Visual Studio.

I have a docker-compose.yml file that lets me spin up the relevant services in docker.

Currently I have to run `docker compose up` manually before starting my application in Visual Studio.

Is there a way to have Visual Studio automatically run `docker compose up` when I start start debugging and have it automatically run `docker compose down` when debugging ends?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have Visual Studio automatically run docker compose
> up when I start start debugging and have it automatically run docker
> compose down when debugging ends?

*To run the `docker compose up`  once done with `docker compose build` it takes a long time to complete the operation even if our container gets created , Then  try to cancel by  using `ctrl+c` and run again with  the below given command in your terminal of visual studio  `docker compose up -d`.*

***To use `docker compose down` it needs to choose the type to delete the images  as shown below once mentioned it will delete based on your requirement.***

[image]

***RUNNING COMMAND SCREENSHOT FOR REFERENCE:-***

[image]

[image]

[image]

For more information please refer the below links :-

- [***MICRSOFT DOCUMENTATION|Visual Studio Container Tools for Docker***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/overview?view=vs-2022)
- [***DOCKER DOCUMENTATION***](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/)